# Is Windows running in VirtualBox that is running in Ubuntu third party software?

Tags: virtualbox

If VirtualBox is running in Ubuntu and Windows is running in VirtualBox is Windows technically and by definition third party software to Ubuntu?

Google Says:

Third Party are ALL software that does not come normally recommended (100% free software) with Ubuntu in the CD/DVD. For example the Flash and MP3 are proprietary (Until a better software emerges which i have high hopes like Lightspark and Gnash).

Comment: To me, only if your virtualbox was installed other than official repositories (ie. not from https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=virtualbox).  That's my opinion, though I suspect others could consider the virtualbox from 'multiverse' 3rd party anyway.

Comment: @guiverc: The question is if Windows running in VBox is Third Party Software, I think that by definition it is.

Comment: I think the answer can only be opinion (*thus off-topic as I understand it for this site*), but if vbox is from Ubuntu repos; whatever is running inside vbox to me is data for the vbox program and thus **not** 3rd party software running on Ubuntu.

Comment: @guiverc VBox is not on the CD, see google definition in the edit, however please consider that VBox was downloaded from virtualbox.org. This usually has a later version than than Ubuntu Software.

Comment: Yes I know; I mentioned that in my first comment (only 'main' repo software is included on ISOs, and I can understand/accept that meaning `virtualbox` itself can be 3rd party).  Myself I tend to consider anything from Ubuntu repositories as official (non-3rd party) & ignore 'multiverse' (*I can't upload there for starters*) - but that issue to me is opinion.  I'm aware some treat 'universe' or community sourced software itself as if 3rd party too, but being associated with a flavor to me it's not 3rd party as we're part of the Ubuntu community.

Comment: question does not belong on AU, Belongs on META. and it already is https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18984/third-party-software so please remove this.

Comment: @Rinzwind : The question has an answer with an upvote and many comments. We would be wasting JosephWorks time if we deleted it, that would not be nice. I recall that is also illegal in Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Vbox would be 3rd party as it is the actual software you are running. Windows 10 (think of it as a file you are opening and running) is not.
Ubuntu doesn't really care what you are doing in virtualbox, so to Ubuntu, windows 10 vm is not a 3rd party software.

Also by:

> Third Party are ALL software that does not come normally recommended (100% free software) with Ubuntu in the CD/DVD.

They are talking about the softwares that are installed with a fresh install of Ubuntu with a CD/DVD, and Virtualbox doesn't come Preinstalled. So, Virtualbox may not even be a 3rd party software

Comment: software that does **not** come normally recommended ...  An operating system (OS) is system software by definition. VirtualBox does not run files, it runs OS's.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron the "OSs" (or VM files) that Virtualbox runs are not softwares, Virtualbox is the software, the OSs are just files on the host drive. The files do not do anything by themselves, they need a Software to run them.

Comment: Are you saying that Windows is just a file, that Ubuntu is just a file? Google says: VirtualBox is a powerful virtualization solution that can be used for **running distinct operating systems** . Wikipedia says:  An operating system (OS) is **system software** that manages computer hardware.

Comment: Yes, you get the idea. Virtualbox runs operating systems, it's the same as VLC running media files or python running python files. Just cause a VM is running doesn't mean it is a software. Again, Virtualbox is the software, the VM is the data. The operating system is managing Virtualbox virtual hardware, like how a program can manage it's programming language.

Comment: So, Is Windows running in VirtualBox that is running in Ubuntu **third party data**? I think that it is on-topic to ask about data running in Ubuntu. You deserve an upvote.